# .NET Framework 4.8 App works on IIS Express but not on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, iis

I created a boilerplate .NET Framework 4.8 Web Forms application in Visual Studio. It runs fine in IIS Express from VS (I can navigate to a home page, about page, contact page).

Now I'd like to get it running on IIS.  When I publish the application to a folder and create a new website in IIS, I first get this error that it can't access the config file. After following another post about adding permissions to IIS_IUSR, when I try to navigate to the website it just sits and loads for eternity.

[image: IIS error]

This is what I'm seeing in the logs at "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC4".

```
2022-09-20 15:50:40 ::1 GET / - 8082 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/105.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/105.0.1343.42 - 500 19 5 122
2022-09-20 15:50:40 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8082 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/105.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/105.0.1343.42 http://localhost:8082/ 500 19 5 6
2022-09-20 15:51:15 ::1 GET / - 8082 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/105.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/105.0.1343.42 - 500 19 5 2
```

Comment: IIS Express installers also bundled common OOB components, but IIS isn't https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: As the error says: *"Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions"*. Whatever user your application pool is running under probably doesn't have permission to access your project folder.

Comment: I would suggest you install the Asp.net Core hosting bundle to host the Asp.net boilerplate app. You could download it from [ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.9](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0). After that restart your site and visit it in the browser. See if it works. Similar thread: [How to publish service on IIS using ASP.NET Boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390497/how-to-publish-service-on-iis-using-asp-net-boilerplate).

Comment: It was either adding the .NET core hosting bundle (didn't think I needed it for a legacy .NET Framework app) or running "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45" in Powershell along with an IIS restart that got things working

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install the Asp.net Core hosting bundle to host the Asp.net boilerplate app.

You could download it from [ASP.NET Core Runtime 6.0.9](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

After that restart your site and visit it in the browser. See if it works.

Similar thread: [How to publish service on IIS using ASP.NET Boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390497/how-to-publish-service-on-iis-using-asp-net-boilerplate)